# rvest table scraping including links

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I would like to scrape some table data from Wikipedia. Some of the table columns include links to other articles I'd like to preserve. I've tried [this approach](http://blog.corynissen.com/2015/01/using-rvest-to-scrape-html-table.html), which didn't preserve the URLs. Looking at the html_table() function description, I didn't find any options of including those. Is there another package or way to do this?

```
library("rvest")

url <- "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_The_Simpsons_episodes"

simp <- url %>%
        html() %>%
        html_nodes(xpath='//*[@id="mw-content-text"]/table[3]') %>%
        html_table()

simp <- simp[[1]]
```

Comment: What do you mean "..preserve the URLs".? The only way I see here is to create a column and fill in related URLS.

Comment: "Preserve" in the sense of "there are a href tags inside the cells I'd like to keep".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
library(XML)
library(httr)
url <- "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_The_Simpsons_episodes"
doc <- content(GET(url))
getHrefs <- function(node, encoding) {  
  x <- xmlChildren(node)$a 
  if (!is.null(x)) paste0("http://", parseURI(url)$server, xmlGetAttr(x, "href"), " | ", xmlValue(x) ) else xmlValue(xmlChildren(node)$text) 
}
tab <- readHTMLTable(doc, which = 3, elFun = getHrefs)
head(tab[, 1:4])
# No. in\nseries No. in\nseason                                                                                              Title                                                               Directed by
# 1              1              1 http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simpsons_Roasting_on_an_Open_Fire | Simpsons Roasting on an Open Fire http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_Silverman_(animator) | David Silverman
# 2              2              2                                     http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bart_the_Genius | Bart the Genius                                                           David Silverman
# 3              3              3                    http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homer%27s_Odyssey_(The_Simpsons) | Homer's Odyssey                      http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wes_Archer | Wes Archer
# 4              4              4       http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/There%27s_No_Disgrace_Like_Home | There's No Disgrace Like Home                    http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gregg_Vanzo | Gregg Vanzo
# 5              5              5                                   http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bart_the_General | Bart the General                                                           David Silverman
# 6              6              6                                           http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moaning_Lisa | Moaning Lisa                                                                Wes Archer
```

The URLs are preserved and separated by a pipe (`|`) from the text. So you could split it up for example by using `strsplit(as.character(tab[, 3]), split = " | ", fixed = TRUE)`.

Comment: Nice, works well, also for other WP URLs. Can you elaborate on what the getHrefs function does?

Comment: The function evaluates every child of `table`: If it contains an anchor `a`, if returns its `href` attribute (preceded by the protocol and the base url) plus the link text. If not, it just returns the childs text.